# getMonth in javascript gives previous month

Tags: javascript, date

I am using a datepicker which gives a date in the format Sun Jul 7 00:00:00 EDT 2013.
Even though the month says July, if I do a getMonth, it gives me the previous month.

```
var d1 = new Date("Sun Jul 7 00:00:00 EDT 2013");
d1.getMonth());//gives 6 instead of 7
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yep... it's [zero indexed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth).

Comment: Don't lose your mind with dates in javascript. Use Moment.js if you can

Comment: i cant believe how real this is

Comment: Moment.js can't do dateDiffs correctly.  It's okay if you're doing dateDiffs within the same month, but try to do it across 2 different months (ie 27-04-2018 and 24-05-2018) and it's a day out.

Comment: Wait until you try `getYear()`!! ;-)

Answer (score 456, accepted):

Because [getmonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) start from 0. You may want to have `d1.getMonth() + 1` to achieve what you want.

Comment: I gotta say, to have a month number zero indexed is the dumbest thing I've seen in a while. '

Comment: why the would someone want it 0 based if getDate gives 1-31?

Comment: Most probably you will have to do `d1.getMonth() < 12 ? d1.getMonth() + 1 : 1` - otherwise December would be 13, not?

Comment: @DanielKhan Nope, because December would be 11, so adding 1 to it would correctly make it 12. The getMonth() function shouldn't ever return a value over 11.

Comment: Ah - sorry it was late.

Comment: getDate should also start with '0' then. :)

Comment: @LarryBud, the reasoning is probably that contrary to other parts of the date (day of month, year, hours, minutes, seconds...) which are always used as numbers as they are, the month is often converted to text, using an array of names, which is of course 0-based. It was already the case in C standard libraries, which must be over 40 years old.

Comment: Another oddity is that to get the day of the month it's getDate but this is not 0 based and returns the correct day. http://momentjs.com/ is the way to go if its available to use

Comment: again, if I was dealing with anything else that would be fine, but since this is a month it should do the logic for you and return the correct number.  It is just dumb.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: The Javascript date interface was adopted directly from the C API with no changes. That propagated such unfortunate choices as getYear() returning the year minus 1900 and getMonth() returning 0..11. Using getFullYear() avoids the first landmine, but you just have to know to use getMonth()+1 if you want the standard month number instead of an index you can use with an array of month names.

Comment: It is not always zero based. `new Date("2023-01-10").getMonth() = 0` but, `new Date(2023, 01, 10).getMonth() = 1` (Firefox 108) -.-

Comment: Thank you for giving us of another reason why JavaScript is just the absolute worst

Answer (score 31):

`getMonth()` function is zero indexed based. You need to do `d1.getMonth() + 1`

Recently I used **[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)** library and never looked back. Try it!

Comment: Can you say how did you use?

Comment: `dayjs` is also a good alternative.

Answer (score 28):

#### Presuming you use your variable

```
var d1 = new Date("Sun Jul 7 00:00:00 EDT 2013");
```

#### Month requires a +1 to be accurate, it starts counting at 0

```
d1.getMonth() + 1 // month
```

#### In contrast.... these methods DON'T need a plus 1

```
d1.getSeconds()   // seconds 
d1.getMinutes()   // minutes 
d1.getDate()      // date
```

#### And notice it is `.getDate()` NOT .`getDay()`

```
d1.getDay()       // day of the week as a
```

#### Hope this helps

***I suspect these methods lack consistency for historical reasons***

Comment: "In contrast.... these methods DON'T need a plus 1" -> it's very nice when you have developers that are consistent...

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH

Answer (score 5):

```
const d = new Date();
const time = d.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second:'numeric', hour12: true });
const date = d.toLocaleString('en-US', { day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year:'numeric' });
```

**OR**

```
const full_date = new Date().toLocaleDateString(); //Date String
const full_time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(); // Time String
```

**Output**

Date = `8/13/2020`

Time = `12:06:13 AM`

Answer (score -1):

you can also find current month in this way

```js
const today = new Date()
const getMonth = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString().length === 1 ? `0${today.getMonth() + 1}`:today.getMonth() + 1
```

Comment: How is this answer any different from the accepted answer... you are still using `getMonth() + 1`???