# JavaScript code messing with date

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I have implemented a simple javascript code which displays the date on a page of mine. The thing is, it is set 1 month back. Today (25/12) it shows 25/11. Can you help me find the problem, cause I still have very basic understanding of JS and created this script following a tutorial. Thanks.

```
<script>
function renderDate() {
    var today = new Date();
    var d = today.getDate();
    var m = today.getMonth();
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    d = checkTime(d);
    m = checkTime(m);
    document.getElementById('dateid').innerHTML = d + "/" + m + "<br> <b>" + y + "</b>";
    t = setTimeout (function() {renderTime()}, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10)
    {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Date() constructor doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163563/javascript-date-constructor-doesnt-work)

Comment: possible duplicate of [getMonth in javascript gives last month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624326/getmonth-in-javascript-gives-last-month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months are zero-based in Javascript, so January is 0, February is 1, so on and so forth, until December is 11. Just add 1 to the `today.getMonth()`, and you'll be fine. Your new code would be

```
<script>
function renderDate() {
    var today = new Date();
    var d = today.getDate();
    var m = today.getMonth()+1;  //Month Increment
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    d = checkTime(d);
    m = checkTime(m);
    document.getElementById('dateid').innerHTML = d + "/" + m + "<br> <b>" + y + "</b>";
    t = setTimeout (function() {renderTime()}, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10)
    {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Month is Starting from zero

Replace

`var m = today.getMonth()`

with

`var m = today.getMonth()+1`

Answer (score 0):

it's easily understand to you , i think :)
it's because the Date.prototype.getMonth() which return 0-11,representing the month 1 - 12

check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)