# Html5 Date control issue: Adding 3 days to a particular date in December returns the next month January in js

Tags: javascript

I have a date object which I am setting based on the value selected by the user, from the drop down calendar.I want to add 3 days to the selected one. Its working perfectly fine for all months, except **December**. If I select a particular date from December and add 3 days, the month value returned is "**00**" instead of "**12**".

Here is my code.

```
var dateinput= document.getElementById("date_picker").value;
      console.log(dateinput);
      var timeinput= document.getElementById("time_picker").value;
      var dateobj = dateinput + ' ' +timeinput;
      var parts = dateobj.split(/[-\s:]/);
      var date  = new Date(parts[0],parts[1],parts[2],parts[3],parts[4]);
      console.log(parts[1])
      date.setDate( date.getDate() + 3);
      console.log(date)


      var dateobj2 = [date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getFullYear()].map(pad).join('/') +
               ' ' + [date.getHours(),date.getMinutes()].map(pad).join(':');
```

Comment: What is the value of `document.getElementById("date_picker").value` ?

Comment: How do you check the month? Via the return value of `getMonth`? `11` is December, `0` is January. There is no month `12`.

Comment: I am getting month using getMonth().

Comment: Printing it as follows. var dateobj2 = [date.getMonth(), date.getDate(),  date.getFullYear()].map(pad).join('/') +
               ' ' + [date.getHours(),date.getMinutes()].map(pad).join(':');

Comment: Which date picker and time picker you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getMonth in javascript gives last month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624326/getmonth-in-javascript-gives-last-month)

Comment: date I am getting from input type="date" time is entered by the user.

Comment: Instead of splitting the date components, can you try like this, `var date  = new Date(dateobj)` ?

Comment: Thats giving error. It wont process according to js date format.

Comment: And the code is working perfectly for all the other months. If I select a date from December say 4/12/2016 its showing correctly. If I add 3, it should be 7/12/2016. But the result is 7/00/2016. I don't know why the month si getting changed.

Comment: @Rayon the value of datepicker is like this "2016-12-05"

Comment: and what value, you gave in the time?

Comment: in this format hh:mm

Comment: @Phoenix Can you check my below answer. It explains the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically months will start from `00 (Jan)` to `11 (Dec)`. So when user enters `12` for December, it should be subtracted by 1 to get 11 when you assign the components to `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`.

So your code will become,

```
var date  = new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4]);
```

You can check the below snippet,

```js
function getDate() {

      var dateinput= document.getElementById("date_picker").value;
      var timeinput= document.getElementById("time_picker").value;
      var dateobj = dateinput + ' ' +timeinput;
      var parts = dateobj.split(/[-\s:]/);
      var date  = new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4]);
      date.setDate( date.getDate() + 3);
      console.log(date);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date_picker" />
<input type="text" id="time_picker" />
<input type="button" value="Get Date" onclick="getDate()" />
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. But now its returning the month as 11. :(

Comment: Sorry, is it displaying 11 for 12?

Comment: Yup. When I do -1. :(

Comment: why are you entering -1 :-) ?

Comment: you should validate this after splitting nd throw error to user.

Comment: if you enter valid date, this will work. If you enter, 01/01/2016, `parts[1]-1` will make this as `00` and for 01/12/2016, it becomes 11.

Comment: when you print the value in the console, you can see the expected answer. The code will have `parts[1]-1`, but you should enter valid date and not `00`

Comment: For end users, its always `01` to `12`, but for the code, it should be `00` to `11`. That conversion is handled by `parts[1]-1`. Hope it clarifies you.

Comment: I am entering valid date only. @Aruna. From dropdown I am selecting.

Comment: Can you explain what you are selecting and happening, I will try the same and execute the above snippet

Comment: I am selecting Dec 7th as the date from the datepicker drop down provide by input type="date" in HTML.

Comment: After executing the above code, I am getting the new date ( that is after adding 3 days) as 10th Jan instead of 10th December.

Comment: Have you executed this in my above snippet?

Comment: When I click "Run code snippet", then enter the date you gave and click the button "Get Date" above, I got this output printed "2016-12-10T09:15:00.000Z"

Comment: I got null when I clicked on Get Date button.

Comment: There is no validation. So you have to provide the time `hh:mm` and year

Comment: Got it. Thanks a million :)

Comment: You saved my life.. By the way my name is also Aruna ;)

Comment: @Phoenix Great :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129515/discussion-between-aruna-and-phoenix).

Answer (score 1):

Below code output http://prntscr.com/ddyjy3

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Date Demo</title>
    <style>
ol {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
}
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="demo"></ul>

<script>
// set start date from your date picker
// set daysToAdd to 3 to return next 3days from the selected date
function showDates(startDate, daysToAdd) {
    var aryDates = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < daysToAdd; i++) {
       var currentDate = new Date();
       currentDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i);
       var fullDate = currentDate.getDate() + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
       aryDates.push('<li class="pick-date" data-date="' + fullDate + '"> ' + currentDate.getDate() + ' <span class="day">' + DayAsString(currentDate.getDay()) + '</span> ('+ fullDate +')</li>');
    }

    return aryDates;
}

function DayAsString(dayIndex) {
    var weekdays = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
    return weekdays[dayIndex];
}

var startDate = new Date();// document.getElementById('date_picker').value
var aryDates = showDates(startDate, 7);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = aryDates.join(" ");


</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In a way the same thing I am doing..date.setDate( date.getDate() + 3);