# Date parsing issue in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

```
let datetimeStamp = '2020-07-11T00:05:00';

let flightDateTime = new Date(datetimeStamp);

flightDateTime.getMonth()
// Output is 6
```

But it should be 7 as per datetimeStamp provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getMonth in javascript gives last month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624326/getmonth-in-javascript-gives-last-month)

Answer (score 2):

`getMonth()` returns values from `0` (for January) to `11` (for December), so you need to manually add `+1` to adjust your value properly:

```
let month = flightDateTime.getMonth() + 1
```

For further details, have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Answer (score 0):

To format date directly in HTML , we can also use **angular date pipe**

```
{{datetimeStamp | date:'MMM dd,yyyy'}}
```

or

```
{{(datetimeStamp | date:'MMM dd,yyyy') || 'No Date Found'}}
```