# getMonth() in Date shows wrong value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the month of the given date as a string in javaScript but I get the wrong month of the date displayed.

```
var d = new Date("Sun Dec 13 2020 08:00:00 GMT+0530");
console.log(d.getMonth());
```

I get in the console output for month as 11 for some reason.

Comment: that's correct. January gives 0 as a result of getMonth()

Comment: dateObj.getMonth() return integer range from 0 to 11. 0 => January, 1 => Feb ...... 11=> December. Check this for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: Understood sir, thank you

Comment: The answer is already in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624326/getmonth-in-javascript-gives-previous-month

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getMonth in javascript gives previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624326/getmonth-in-javascript-gives-previous-month)

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

The range begins at zero and not at one

So refering the **mdn** docs

> monthIndex Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for
> January to 11 for December.

The range from `getMonth()` is **0-11**

So the **solution** is just to **add +1** to the result of the `getMonth()` method

```
console.log(d.getMonth() +1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

the count starts from 0 -january, 1-feb,...11-december

Answer (score -1):

just call this and it is done.

```
function month(){
 const today = new Date();
 const options = {
    month: "long"
  };

  return today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
}
```