# javascript getMonth() off by 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I understand that [getMonth() is zero indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624326/getmonth-in-javascript-gives-previous-month?newreg=aefa28b8512c4e068f7b6389046c3859) so, for example, June is 5. But I'm getting that it's 'off' by 2 in some situations.

```
myDate = new Date(1622513190000)
month = myDate.getMonth()

console.log(myDate)
console.log(month)
```

Returns:

> 2021-06-01T02:06:30.000Z

> 4

Anyone have an idea why this is returning 4 and not 5? I'm using node v14.15.5 and am getting the expected result for other dates (September is 8, August is 7)

Thanks!

Comment: 2am zulu time on the 1st, so if *your* timezone is GMT-3:00 or further west (e.g. you're in North America) it's still May where you are.

Comment: Try `myDate.getUTCMonth()`. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome here :)

Working with dates and timezone is a bit tricky, everyone here can attest it. For general information, I suggest you to read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) about Coordinated universal time.

The `Z` you can see in `myDate` value means `Zulu time`, military name for UTC±00:00, the reference timezone. `±00:00` represents an eventual offset with the Zulu time.

After having gone crazy about this question, I advice you to :

- **always** get and store dates in Zulu format, and then compute time lapse with them
- you can show users local dates, but it's only to display them. If you have to compute with a user input, first get the UTC equivalent (as @RobG advised).

Good luck ! :)

Comment: That is super helpful - thank you!

Comment: @pacificpythagoras, glad to read it :) Happy coding !