# Apps Script Calendar API getStartTime

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am extracting and formatting the Date from a Google Calendar Event with:

```
  var date = event.getStartTime();
  var dateString = date.getDate() + "." + date.getMonth() + "." + date.getFullYear();
```

But i get 10.7.2023 for a Date in August?!

Is getStartTime broken?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that this thread will be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/18624326 In your script, please add `1` to `date.getMonth()` like `var dateString = date.getDate() + "." + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "." + date.getFullYear();`.